# Stop VS Code from using Apple CoreSimulator?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

Normally, com.apple.coresimulator.coresimulatorservice sits on my machine and does nothing, taking up 0% of the CPU on my machine.  When I run VS Code, com.apple.coresimulator.coresimulatorservice constantly runs at 25% cpu, causing the fans on my Macbook to run loud.  I've searched and don't see any information on it.  I was wondering if there was some way to tell VS Code that I do not want the Apple simulator to run.  I need to keep it around for when I am working in Xcode but will not use it when working in VS Code.